# How can I interact with IPython from within a python app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

I'd like to create an app that would allow the user to do some ipython commands of their own within the app. What I would like is something that would allow me to do something like this:

```
from IPython import Session
session = Session()
session.input("value = 10")
myvalue = session.get("value")

print(myvalue)

10
```

Does something like this exist within the IPython package? I am finding in the documentation things like embed, etc. but it doesn't seem to be quite what I want. I would ultimately like something that allows me to send it code from my own app, and then get variables set by that code out from it and into my app.

Comment: Would simply using the `exec("code")` work instead, rather than trying to launch IPython?

Comment: @LarrytheLlama possibly, though IPython has some features I think I like. That being said, at the end of the day this is going to be user defined input, so perhaps I should avoid any sort of direct execution all together.